# Return the optimal amount of products to "fill" a certain size var

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I have an array of objects with a property called size. See example array below.

```
   var products = [{"name":"product 1", "size":25},{"name":"product 2", "size":15},{"name":"product 3", "size":3}]
```

I'm looking for an algorithm that returns the optimal amount of products to "fill" a certain size.
By optimal I mean it returns the lowest amount of products with the least amount of leftover size.

For example, let's say the target size is 72. I would like to return the following products:
2 x product 1
1 x product 2
3 x product 3

The array is ordered from highest to lowest size.

I have tried the following (this is a simplified version of my code).
For now I'm simply console logging the results.

```
var totalSize = 72
products.forEach(function (arrayItem) {
  if(multiplierSize / arrayItem.size >= 1) {
    var minTimes = Math.floor(totalSize / arrayItem.size);
    var minAmount = (minTimes * arrayItem.size);
    multiplierSize -= minAmount;
    console.log(arrayItem.name + " x " + minTimes)
  }
});
```

The above example won't properly fill out the total size and will result in the following:
2 x product 1
1 x product 2
2 x product 3
Any help that could point me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: why 3x product 3? 50 + 15 + 9 = 74

Comment: `24 * 3 == 72`. Would that be preferable in your case? Either way, this sounds like a kind of problem you see in math textbooks... Maybe [Math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/) can help you out with some logic.

Comment: That said,  `4 * 15 + 4 * 3 === 72` is probably the desired answer here.

Comment: I think you problem is a [Knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem). You could solve it with the  [Simplex method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex_algorithm) But that more a mathematical question, not a javascript one.

Comment: ^ That was the word I was looking for.

Comment: what is the wanted result of it? which value is more important, the smaleste leftover or the smaller count of parts? for example, you could have `3 0 0`  with 75, `2 1 3` with 74, `1 3 1` with 73. which one of the three is the optimum, you want to get?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you are not required to include at least one of every product. If that should be the case then the below solution won't work. I'm also not sure what you want the end result to look like but basically you can use a recursive function that checks each products and it's size, sees how many times it goes into the passed `total` and then creates a `newTotal` based on that. As you iterate through the products, determine the amount of times a product can go into the `newTotal`, store the `amount` and he product `name` in an object and push it into `calcSizes`. Then check if the `newTotal` is equal to the passed `total`. If so, log `calcSizes`, otherwise, reorder the products so the second one becomes the first one and the first one is pushed to the back. Then call the `evalProducts` and pass `total` and the the new products array.

Note: I use `Math.trunc` instead of `Math.round` to be conservative in calculating the amount since I'm assuming negative amounts are not permitted. For example, using `Math.round` when passing the original number 72, you would end up with the below result.

```
  {
    "name": "product 1",
    "amount": 3
  },
  {
    "name": "product 2",
    "amount": 0
  },
  {
    "name": "product 3",
    "amount": -1
  }
]
```

I tried the function with a few numbers in addition to the original 72. I am not sure if this is the most optimal solution as I do not have a math background but from a JS perspective and talking in terms of time complexity I think it is reasonable.

```js
var products = [{
  "name": "product 1",
  "size": 25
}, {
  "name": "product 2",
  "size": 15
}, {
  "name": "product 3",
  "size": 3
}]

var potentialCalcSizes = {}

const evalProducts = (total, newProducts) => {
  var calcSizes = []
  var newTotal = 0
  var prods = newProducts ? newProducts.slice() : products.slice();
  //reset potentialCalcSizes
  potentialCalcSizes = newProducts ? potentialCalcSizes : {}
  prods.forEach(function(arrayItem) {
    var calcSize = {}
    var calcNum
    if (newTotal === 0) {
      calcNum = Math.trunc(total / arrayItem.size)
      calcSize['name'] = arrayItem.name
      calcSize['amount'] = calcNum
      newTotal = calcNum * arrayItem.size
    } else {
      calcNum = Math.trunc((total - newTotal) / arrayItem.size)
      calcSize['name'] = arrayItem.name
      calcSize['amount'] = calcNum
      newTotal += calcNum * arrayItem.size
    }
    calcSizes.push(calcSize)
  });
  if (total === newTotal) {
    return calcSizes
  } else {
    potentialCalcSizes[newTotal] = calcSizes
    var first = prods[0];
    var second = prods[1];
    prods.shift();
    prods.push(first)
    if (products[0].name === prods[0].name) {
      return findNextClosest(potentialCalcSizes, total)
    } else {
      return evalProducts(total, prods)
    }
  }
}

const findNextClosest = (obj, total) =>{
   var closestToTotal = Infinity;
   Object.keys(potentialCalcSizes).forEach(x=>{
      if (Math.abs(total-parseInt(x)) < closestToTotal){
        closestToTotal = parseInt(x)
      }
   })
   return obj[closestToTotal]
}

console.log('72')
console.log(evalProducts(72))
console.log('78')
console.log(evalProducts(78))
console.log('82')
console.log(evalProducts(82))
console.log('75')
console.log(evalProducts(75))
```

Comment: For some reason your code returns `no solution` for items of size 5 and 3 and capacity to fill 11 (whereas 1x5+2x3 is perfectly valid)

Comment: Regardless of the reason, I don't think OP seeks for solution where leftover size is always 0, so there should be no `no solution` return, whatsoever.

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov I updated the snippet to return the next optimal solution: calcSizes that result in the closet possible total to the original total.

Comment: Back to my above test case, now it returns 2x5 to fill 11, rather than 1x5+2x3

Comment: This seems occasionally seems to generate some strange results. See the following array: [{"name": "product 120","size": 120}, {"name": "product 60","size": 60}, {"name": "product 40","size": 40}, {"name": "product 20","size": 20}, {"name": "product 6","size": 6}] and a target size of 321. In this case it will return Product 20 x 16. Also, maybe I phrased the question wrong but preferably I want to completely fill the target size. So the total product amount sum can exceed the target size.

Comment: Thank you clarifying I didn't realize it could exceed the target size. As for the strange results I believe this is happening for a few cases (see YevgenGorbunkov's comments above) I was working on a better solution but I think NinaSholz's answer is more sufficient

Answer (score 1):

You could take a brute force approach and collect all possible combinations and filter the result by taking only the ones with minimum counts and totals.

The result set contains arrays with

- count of items at the same index,
- total of sizes,
- counts of all items.

Example of filtering of raw result:

```
       indices     totals  counts  comment
       ----------  ------  ------  ---------------------------------------
raw      3            75       3
         2  2         80       4
         2  1  3      74       6
         2  8         74      10
         1  4         85       5
         1  3  1      73       5
         1  2  6      73       9
         1  1 11      73      13
         1 16         73      17
         5            75       5
         4  4         72       8
         3  9         72      12
         2 14         72      16
         1 19         72      20
        24            72      24

1st      3            75       3   get the smallest of every group
filter   2  2         80       4   
         2  1  3      74       6
         1  3  1      73       5
         4  4         72       8

2nd      3            75       3   is better than  2  2         80       4
filter   1  3  1      73       5   is better than  2  1  3      74       6
         4  4         72       8   has no comparable value
```

```js
function getParts(array, target) {
    function iter(index, temp, total, push) {
        if (push && total >= target) {
            var count = temp.reduce((a, b) => a + b);
            result.push([temp.join(' '), total, count]);
            if (!totals.has(total) || count < totals.get(total)) totals.set(total, count);
            if (!counts.has(count) || total < counts.get(count)) counts.set(count, total);
            return;
        }

        if (index >= array.length) return;

        var l = Math.ceil((target - total) / array[index].size);

        do iter(index + 1, [...temp, l], total + l * array[index].size, true);
        while (--l)

        iter(index + 1, temp, total, false);
    }

    var result = [],
        totals = new Map,
        counts = new Map;

    iter(0, [], 0);

    return result
        .filter(([, total, count]) =>
            totals.get(total) === count &&
            counts.get(count) === total
        )
        .filter(([, total, count], _, array) =>
            array.some(a => total < a[1] && count < a[2]) ||
            !array.some(a => total > a[1] && count > a[2]) 
        );
}

var products = [{ "name": "product 1", "size": 25 }, { "name": "product 2", "size": 15 }, { "name": "product 3", "size": 3 }],
    target = 72,
    result = getParts(products, target);

result.forEach(a => console.log(a.join(' | ')));
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Could you expand on this a little bit? How would I actually log or return the products, instead of just the count and total size?

Comment: Least amount of leftover size has priority.

Comment: what do you want from the raw result?

Answer (score -1):

You could try a linear optimizsation lib for js, e.g. https://www.npmjs.com/package/simple-simplex.

Just define your optimization problem like a [Knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem)

Your only constraints would be

```
25a + 15b + 3c <= 72
```

and your objective to minimize `a + b +c`

I think the documentation of `simple-simplex` will explain everythin you need.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: @Cerbrus True, i just added some detailed information

Comment: Sorry, but that still basically says “look at the contents of this link”...